# Top CPU Utilization - Node Name

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to save node name which consuming highest CPU (in the current namespace) into the file.

`kubectl top node` provide you all nodes information, need to pick the top one from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal command to get the sorted list is `kubectl top node --no-headers --sort-by='cpu' | head -1 > somefilename.txt`, but the result will be inconsistent due to open issue [kubectl top issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81270)

As a workaround you can try this command if you are running in any linux/mac OS:

`kubectl top node --no-headers | sort -k3 -n | tail -1 > somefilename.txt`

This issue has been resolved in kubectl 1.18.